# How to create a table using tableviewer which has 2 coloumns and 10 rows in jface

Tags: java, swt, jface

How to create a table using TableViewer which has 2 columns and 10 rows.I am trying to create a table using the above link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html

i am not able to develop it .So please help me to do as i am new to jface

I have created the columns of the table but i am not able to add the data into it using content provider and label so please help me to do.The code to create the column header is as follows

```
TableColumnLayout layout = new TableColumnLayout();
composite.setLayout(layout);

//Instantiate TableViewer
TableViewer tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
table = tableViewer.getTable();
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
table.setLinesVisible(true);

TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
TableColumn empty = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();

layout.setColumnData(empty, new ColumnPixelData(100, true, true));
empty.setText("");

TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn_Time = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
TableColumn time = tableViewerColumn_Time.getColumn();
//Specify width using weights
layout.setColumnData(time, new ColumnWeightData(2, ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
time.setText("Time");

TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn_2 = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
TableColumn message = tableViewerColumn_2.getColumn();
//Specify width using weights
layout.setColumnData(message, new ColumnWeightData(4, ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
message.setText("Message");
```

Comment: This is too broad especially as that tutorial covers most things. Show us what you have written and what you are having problems with.

Comment: I have created the coloumns of the table but i am not able to add the data into it using content provider and label so please help me to do.The code to create the coloumn header is as follows  in the qustion above

Answer (score 0):

You need a class containing the data for the rows, something like:

```
class MyRowData
{
  String getTime()
  {
     ... your code
  }

  String getMessage()
  {
     .... your code
  }
}
```

Add column label providers to your columns which get the data from your class:

```
tableViewerColumn_Time.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() { 
  @Override
  public String getText(Object element) {
    return ((MyRowData)element).getTime();
  }
});

tableViewerColumn_2.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() { 
  @Override
  public String getText(Object element) {
    return ((MyRowData)element).getMessage();
  }
});
```

Use a standard array / list content provider:

```
tableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
```

Create a list containing your rows:

```
List<MyRowData> rows = new ArrayList<>();

rows.add(new MyRowData(..... 
....
```

Tell the table viewer to use the list:

```
tableViewer.setInput(rows);
```

This `setInput` call must be done last.